# Show progress of spatial vector data in R

Tags: r, vector, geospatial, progress, r-raster

I am searching for a method to show progress when doing spatial operations in R. I know there are some for working with raster-data. Does anyone know a way to show progress when doing an operation with vactor-data like union{raster}? It would really help to organize our workflow here.

Thanks

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding and 'progress' is a technical term, you can use a progress bar `?txtProgressBar`

Comment: @Swarch Yes, I am looking for something similar. But I am searching for a display of progress for spatial data operations. There are many ways to show the progress if you use loops. But I need it for single function like described above.

Comment: that is not available